# Enchanted weapon wasting all of its energy

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did a enchantment on my ebony sword that absorbs 150 points off life at first it worked right but after the first few recharges it wasted all its energy in the first hit does anyone know why this happens and I'm level  72  in enchanting and I used a fortify enchantment potion that I created by doing a glitch that I saw in YouTube

Comment: It might help to diagnose the problem if you could link to the video demonstrating the glitch.

Comment: @TrentHawkins I'm going to assume that it's the "Fortify enchanting potion->fortify alchemy enchantment rinse and repeat" glitch. (It's debatable on whether or not this is a "glitch" oer se, but it's highly exploitable)

Comment: @Unionhawk to get to 150 absorb life, he needed to have used the fortify restoration glitch.  You can't get absorb to those levels with just the enchanting->alchemy feedback.

Answer (score 10):

This is because you glitch enchanted your weapon.

The amount of charges used up per hit depends on your enchanting skill.  At some point it must have recalculated your usage cost so now it drains after 1 hit.

There is an rather convoluted solution to get around this if you are interested:

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:313744